# Printing control with C

Tags: c, math

when i execute the below code, the compiler returns the message "(.text+0x31): undefined reference to 'sqrt'". but if i take away the q* the compiler correctly gives me 8.000000
i'm trying to get the program to multiply the INCREMENT by 1 (and eventually 2 and 3 when i write the loop in).

how come the below doesn't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INCREMENT   64

int main () 
{
    int q = 1;
    printf("%f", sqrt(q*INCREMENT));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong macro name, IN = EX.  The IN version uses 64.0

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to link to the math library. (though I thought visual C++ does this automatically...)

The reason why it works without the `q` is because the compiler is optimizing out the `sqrt` since it's a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct c code.  I tested it under vs 2010 and it returned the value 8.  However it is not correct c++ code.  sqrt becomes ambigueous when the argument is an integer.  Is it possible that your source file has a **.cpp** extension, instead of a **.c** extension?